# Prevent Logic Pro X from scrolling to the top while using Flex Pitch

Tags: logic-pro

When using Flex Pitch Logic snaps to the top of the track overview even though the track I have selected and that I'm working on is way down.

Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1):

Shrink the vertical zoom of your tracks so that all of your tracks are visible without scrolling and it won’t snap to the top. There is a slider near the top right of the window that controls the vertical zoom.